# Adobe Air load local HTML

Tags: air, adobe, urlloader

When I load index.html from IDE it works fine!
But when I start compiled application it doesn't work.

The code:

```
_html = new HTMLLoader();
var fileURL:String = "app:/components/posteditor/ckeditor/index.html";
_html.load( new URLRequest(fileURL) );
```

I tried to load this file with

```
var fileURL:String = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("components/posteditor/ckeditor/index.html").nativePath;
```

but with no luck.

Looks like as Adobe's bug. Can you help me and advice?

Comment: How about FileReference like this page. http://englishblog.flepstudio.org/adobe-air/loading-a-local-text-file-with-adobe-air/